# Javascript get steps index based on array lenth

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of items for which I want to create steps based on their index and the length of the array.

The minimum value should be 0 and the maximum 100.

I don't know if I'm explaining it right, but for example. I have this array:

```
const RAMmarks = [
    {
      value: 0,
      label: ">1024 MB",
    },
    {
      value: 25,
      label: ">2048 MB",
    },
    {
      value: 50,
      label: ">4096 MB",
    },

    {
      value: 75,
      label: ">6144 MB",
    },

    {
      value: 100,
      label: ">8192 MB",
    },
  ];
```

...but then the other one has less items:

```
const diskMarks = [
    {
      value: 0,
      label: ">20 GB",
    },
    {
      value: 33,
      label: ">45 GB",
    },
    {
      value: 66,
      label: ">75 GB",
    },

    {
      value: 99,
      label: ">100 GB",
    },
  ];
```

How do I get the values dynamically based on how many steps the array has?

Comment: Sure, im preparing the data shape i get from the backend to be as i need them and then will mark one of the answers. I think all are great. Thanks!

Comment: Do any of the answers below solve your issue? If not, what are they missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and a map function. Due to how arrays are stored, `{length: steps}` acts as an array-like object with `steps` empty elements, then the map function transforms each empty element into its value. Try using this code:

```js
function stepArray(min, max, steps) {
  return Array.from({length: steps}, (_, i) => ((max-min)/(steps-1))*i + min);
}

console.log(stepArray(0, 100, 5));
```

The idea is to get the difference between `max` and `min`, divide that difference into `step-1` steps (because we need to include both of the endpoints), multiply that step by the current step `i`, then add back the `min` that was subtracted in the beginning.

Note that if you are using uneven intervals, you might want to use `Math.floor()` to get nicer numbers. Expand the snippet below to see an example:

```js
function stepArray(min, max, steps) {
  return Array.from({length: steps}, (_, i) => Math.floor(((max-min)/(steps-1))*i + min));
}

// without Math.floor(), these would all be repeating decimals
console.log(stepArray(0, 100, 10));
```

Once you have this basic array of values, you can then easily transform it into your more complex array of marks.

Comment: Hi Miachel, Your answer looks as the best one. Its so dynamic, but im getting some errors because of my data shape i think and don't want to enter a long discussion here. Maybe we can chat when you have time?

Comment: @Ilir Unfortunately I don't really have the time for a long discussion. I'm not entirely sure what your problem is, but I think you just need to use a `.map()`. If you're confused or having more problems, then I'd suggest posting your errors and code as a new question.

Comment: Ok, i think my issue is more related to my MaterialUI filter slider i am using and it's out of scope of this discussion. Your answer is the best, very dynamic and reusable. However i returned an object from here with a `value:` and `label:` just as @izaiasmachado did in the other answer. So he gets an upvote for that.

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this. Had to add the `floor` to make it work for your second example.

```js
const RAMmarks = [
  {
    value: 0,
    label: ">1024 MB",
  },
  {
    value: 25,
    label: ">2048 MB",
  },
  {
    value: 50,
    label: ">4096 MB",
  },

  {
    value: 75,
    label: ">6144 MB",
  },

  {
    value: 100,
    label: ">8192 MB",
  },
];

const diskMarks = [
  {
    value: 0,
    label: ">20 GB",
  },
  {
    value: 33,
    label: ">45 GB",
  },
  {
    value: 66,
    label: ">75 GB",
  },

  {
    value: 99,
    label: ">100 GB",
  },
];

Array.prototype.addStep = function () {
  return this.map((mark, index) => {
    return {
      label: mark.label,
      value: index * Math.floor(100 / (this.length - 1)),
    };
  });
};

const RAMmarksStep = RAMmarks.addStep();
const diskMarksStep = diskMarks.addStep();

console.log(RAMmarksStep);
console.log(diskMarksStep);
```

Comment: Modifying `Array.prototype` is a really, really, super bad idea. See [Why is extending the DOM/built-in object prototypes a bad idea?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104320/why-is-extending-the-dom-built-in-object-prototypes-a-bad-idea). This was also the exact cause of [SmooshGate](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/smooshgate/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to add the values to your items:

```
function addMarks(items) {
    let steps = items.length - 1;
    let step = 100 / steps;
    for(let i in items) {
        items[i].value = Math.round(i * step);
    }
    return items;
}
```

Based on the example you provided, you might want to swap Math.round for Math.floor